# Problem with using IntlDateFormatter()->format()

Tags: php, datetime, internationalization, strftime, intldateformatter

I have a problem using the IntlDateFormatter class.

The following code gives different results if it is executed by apache or cli

```
<?php

$obj_formato = new IntlDateFormatter(setlocale(LC_TIME, 0), null, null);
$obj_formato->setPattern("MMM");
for($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {
    print $obj_formato->format(strtotime("2022-$i-01")) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Apache:**
ene.
feb.
mar.
abr.
may.
jun.
jul.
ago.
**sept.**
oct.
nov.
dic.

**CLI:**
ene.
feb.
mar.
abr.
may.
jun.
jul.
ago.
**sep.**
oct.
nov.
dic.

The result by CLI returns "Sept.", by Apache it returns "Sep."
It is also the only month where the returned result contains 4 letters

I am using PHP 7.4.33

Any help?

I'm trying to get the short names of the months without using strftime()

Comment: There are locales that use "Sep" and others use "Sept" - chances are, your default locale in the web server is different from the default cli locale.

Comment: I was finally able to work around using Locale::getDefault() as the first parameter of IntlDateFormatter()

Thank you!